# PHP OOP boolean error

Tags: php

I have got the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function count() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\pianocourse101\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pianocourse101\index.php on line 5

I have been wondering whether is the error part of my function count in my `db.php` or from index.php? Here is my code:

#### db.php

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo, 
        $_query, 
        $_error = false,
        $_results,
        $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.Config::get('mysql/host').';dbname='.Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'),Config::get('mysql/password'));

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
       $this->_error = false; 
        // set the error to false so that we are not returning a previous error
       if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {                           
    // check to see if query has been prepared properly
          $x=1;
          if(count($params)) {             // check to see if need to bind 
                                           anything
             foreach($params as $param) {
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
             }
          }

          if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();        // to query a 
            database securely by binding parameters and preventing sql 
              injections
          } else {
               $this->_error = true;
          }
       }

       return $this;      // return the currenct object we are working with
    }

    public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
       if(count($where) === 3) {
          $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

          $field    = $where[0];
          $operator = $where[1];
          $value    = $where[2];

          if(in_array($operator, $operators)) { 
             $sql = "{$action} * FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";    
             if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
             }// to check to see if operator is inside the operators .... We do a     ? so that we can bind the value on
          }
       }
       return false;
    }

    public function get($table, $where){
       return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
    }

      public function delete($table, $where) {
        return $this->action('DELETE ', $table, $where);
     }

      public function error() {
         return $this->_error;
      }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
```

#### index.php

```
<?php
require_once 'core/init.php';

$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));             

if (!$user->count()) {
    echo 'No user';
} else {
    echo 'OK!';
}
```

Comment: share the code how you are calling these functions ? or from where you get this error ? otherwise this question is unclear.

Comment: I got the following code from codecourse. Here is my db.php code:

Comment: We need more context. Show us where you create the db-instance and when you're trying to call `->count()`. Basically, show us _all_ relevant code. Especially where you actually get the error. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your query is failing. With some proper error handling you would have seen why. From your `get()` function, your calling `action()` with `SELECT *`. You put that in a query `{$action} * FROM` which results in a query like: `SELECT * * FROM`...

Comment: I would recommend using a tried and tested db-library instead. There are many out there that are small and super easy to use. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: please, remove those lines of code, which isn't relevant.

Comment: @SalimIbrogimov - They are most definitely relevant to the question and the issue since that's the class the OP is using when the error occurs.

Comment: `$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));             
if (!$user->count()) {`. Your `$user` is it an Object? cause you calling a `$user->count()` function of an object.

Comment: To be honest, I am new to php and am following the tutorial on codecourse but he didn't get any errors...

Comment: If this is the code from a tutorial, I would recommend looking for another. This code isn't very good, since it doesn't take error handling/debugging into account. There are _many_ tutorials out there. You're basically asking us to help you debug someone else code. Learn the basics and take it one step at the time. Test each part separately. In my opinion, that's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get()` method will always fail since it's generating an invalid SQL query.

### Explanation

If we take your request:

```
$user = DB::getInstance()->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));
```

and break it up to see what happens (this is the same thing as the above):

```
// This will work and return an instance of DB
$db = DB::getInstance();

// Will always fail and return false, since the get() method fails
$user = $db->get('users', array('username', '=', 'alex'));

// Since user is false (a boolean), it doesn't have any methods
$user->count()
```

So, why does it fail? Let's look in your DB class.

Let's start with the `get()` method:

```
public function get($table, $where){

    // This is calling an internal method called "action()" passing three values

    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}
```

and where it fails, the `action()` method:

```
public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if(count($where) === 3) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field    = $where[0];
        $operator = $where[1];
        $value    = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) { 

            // The get() method passed 'SELECT *' to this method, so the below string will be
            // "SELECT * * FROM users WHERE username = ?" 
            // (hint: it's the double * * that's invalid) .

            $sql = "{$action} * FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";
            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {

                // Since the query fails, it will never come here

                return $this;
            }
        }
   }

   // Since the query fails (is invalid), this is what it will return

   return false;
}
```

### Solution

A quick fix would be to change the `action()` method from:

```
$sql = "{$action} * FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?"
```

to

```
$sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?"
```

As I've mentioned in comments, you should look into proper error handling for PDO. Or better yet, use some tried and tested db library.

You mentioned that you are new to PHP and are going through some tutorial, the would recommend learning the basics step by step.

Comment: You are a legend! I am such an idiot and after I went through the tutorial again, he did get rid of the star sign. How did I miss that?

Comment: @piano0011 No worries. If it solved the issue, feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: I have another question. At line 4, because I set the name to Alex, will this only find the name that has Alex in it? I have two names in my datasbase called Alex and Bily, what if I want to find the name bily, I would have to change that to bily or it won't work?

Comment: @piano0011 - The request will only find the name you send in. So if you send in Alex, you will only get the user called Alex. You would need to make another request to fetch Billy. If you want to get _all_ users, you could change the call to: `$db->get('users', array('1', '=', 1));`. That would make the query `SELECT * FROM users WHERE 1=1` (which is the same as not having any WHERE statement at all and will return _all_ records).

Comment: So because I have two names here, can I think of it as trying to store the name Alex=0 and Billy=1?

Comment: @piano0011 No. Since your DB method `get()` requires you to send in a condition, you can send in a condition that will always evaluate as `true`. You can change `1=1` to `1234=1234` or what ever arbitrary number you want. No matter what the record actually contains, `1` will always be equal to `1`.

Comment: @piano0011 - This is basically why I suggest you go with some existing database library instead. Your DB class is _very_ limited. It can only select data based on one (required) condition. Sometimes you want want multiple conditions, grouped conditions, joins, sub queries etc. The same goes for the `delete()` method. It's also lacking any `update()` and `insert()`. If you just want to learn SQL from scratch, then you're better off using PDO directly instead of over complicating it by building a DB class. At least to start with.

Comment: @piano0011 - If this answer solved your original question, you should accept it to let other people know that this question has been resolved.

Comment: My apologies.. I have managed to get it to work because there was a typo.. Thanks!